# Error while implementing Json in android

Tags: android, json

I am new to android I am using the following code to parse the data and connect with the database and hence get the value present in the database which is present in the server.

The code which I am using is :-

```
package com.example.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();         <------Here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
   /* public void writeJSON() {
          JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
          try {
            object.put("name", "Prathamesh");
            object.put("score", new Integer(200));
            object.put("current", new Double(152.32));
            object.put("nickname", "Programmer");
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.out.println(object);
        } 
*/
}
```

I am using another code to use the value of json and display it.It is as follows:-

```
package com.example.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
{

//url to make request
private static String url = "http://192.168.0.100:3000/users.json";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FIRST = "first_name";
private static final String TAG_MIDDLE = "middle_name";
private static final String TAG_LAST = "last_name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String TAG_MOBILE = "mobile";

private static final String TAG_USERS = "user";

// users JSONArray
JSONArray users = null;



        @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_test1);


        // Hashmap for ListView
          ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); <---url I am using is http://192.168.0.100:3000/users.json

            try {
                // Getting Array of Contacts
            users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for(int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = users.optJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String first = c.getString(TAG_FIRST);
                    String middle = c.getString(TAG_MIDDLE);
                    String last = c.getString(TAG_LAST);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                    String mobile = c.getString(TAG_MOBILE);




                    // creating new HashMap

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_FIRST, first);
                    map.put(TAG_MIDDLE,middle);
                    map.put(TAG_LAST, last);
                    map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
                    map.put(TAG_MOBILE, mobile);
                    map.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    userList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

My error log file is:-

```
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.library/com.example.library.SecondActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP entity may not be null
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1487)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:654)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:132)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP entity may not be null
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:110)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:146)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.example.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:55)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.example.library.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:51)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

While using the code `json = sb.toString();` I am get the value.whereas json is calling some values from the database from the second code.

Please help me and let me know if there is anything wrong with the code

Comment: What is error? put logs here..

Comment: @PankajKumar There is no such error.Just not getting any value in json = sb.toString();
Hence debugger stops at this point

Comment: @PeeVee Are you sure the charset is correct what is the url you are requesting?

Comment: @Emil The charset according to me is correct and the url I am requesting is url = "http://192.168.0.100:3000/users.json"

Comment: @PeeVee That is a private IP, can't do anything with that. But I believe that the JSON encoding should probably be `UTF-8`.

Comment: @Emil Can u Suggest what I should do I am a newbie to android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
           // parsing JSON
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(retSrc); //Convert String to JSON Object
```

instead of

```
  try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();         <------Here
   } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
   }
```

Edit: I was aspectin you method will look like:

```
public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
     JSONArray json = null;
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        if (httpResponse != null && httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity); 
           // parsing JSON
            json = new JSONArray(retSrc); //Convert String to JSON Object
        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // return JSON String
    return json;

}
```

Comment: now I am getting a null value at jObj = new JSONObject(json);

Comment: In the snippet I provided for you json is already a JsonObject. Can you check the vaule of "retSrc"

Comment: Please check the above edited question.If i make changes to Json.java it is giving error in other files

Comment: It stops (debugger) at JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); in the sondactivity.java

Comment: I see and what's the error? You can retrieve it through logcat

Comment: 04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at com.example.library.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:51)
04-30 16:24:05.697: E/AndroidRuntime(687):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

Comment: is getJSONFromUrl running on the UI Thread ? Are you getting the NetworkOnMainThreadException ?

Comment: no i am not getting NetworkOnMainThreadException.Am getting null pointer exception

Comment: can you post the whole crashlog?

Comment: is    users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS); where do you get the NPE?

Comment: Yes i get null pointer exception at  users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);

Comment: Seems to be a backend issue. Do you forget to set the Entity for the response ? Are you developing the Backend?

Comment: I did not develop the back end.Can u tell me what seems to be the problem and how i should solve it

Comment: it does not seems related to the client. Can you try to reach the url with a browser and see if it download the json ?

Comment: i am getting the output:-[{"admin":null,"card_no":null,"created_at":"2013-04-29T12:38:04Z","deleted":0,"email":null,"entered_by":null,"first_name":null,"id":23,"last_name":null}]

Comment: ok. Now, please, edit your question and past the getJSONFromUrl you are currently using

Comment: I am getting an unhandled exception at  JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url); in secondactivity.java

Comment: Should I use surround with try/catch and initialize json

Comment: could you add the catch to the surronding thy block ?

Comment: 04-30 17:49:16.827: E/AndroidRuntime(725): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 17:49:16.827: E/AndroidRuntime(725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.library/com.example.library.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 17:49:16.827: E/AndroidRuntime(725):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-30 17:49:16.827: E/AndroidRuntime(725)

Comment: it is different now. You are no more getting the IllegalArgumentException

Comment: What do u suggest from here and is this an common error in android

Comment: Also the server is returning you a JSonArray not a JSonObject. check my edit

Comment: Should I change type of json to jsonarray in second activity.java  or change return type of getJsonfromUrl

Comment: users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS); is showing change to optJSONArray.Even when i change there is no difference

Comment: I am getting:- The method getJSONArray(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29188/discussion-between-blackbelt-and-peevee)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
final String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

instead of:

```
json = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is the `charset` is wrong, JSON should usually be in `UTF-8`, try :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 1024);
```

Also increase the buffer size from 8 to 1024.

Comment: now I am getting a null value at jObj = new JSONObject(json);